# Hide records that are not matching search box filter

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2010.
I have a table named "Dashboard"
I have a field named "Client Name"
In my tab named "Search Form" I have a subform called "Dashboard_subform"
The code is working corectly but I have two minor issues:
1. When combo box is empty and i press enter then ***Run-time error "Extra ) in query expression '([Client Name] = )'.***

2. All records are showing up when the combo box is empty. I want no records to show up until i search the particular field data is typed in the combo box. Only records matching the data typed in the combo box must be listed.

```
Private Sub SearchClientRecords_AfterUpdate()

    Me.SearchClientRecords.AutoExpand = False

    Dim myclient As String

    myclient = "Select * from [Dashboard] where ([Client Name] = " & Me.SearchClientRecords & ")"

    Me.Dashboard_subform.Form.RecordSource = myclient

    Me.Dashboard_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

I assumed "AutoExpand" False will hide all records until a entry is typed in the combo box.
Also not sure why the run time error is showing up because the closed paranthesis is needed in this case.

Comment: Those parentheses are not necessary. Apostrophe delimiters are if [Client Name] is a text type field. Why don't you search on client ID?

Comment: AutoExpand has nothing to do with hiding records on form. All it does is fill the combobox with matching value from list as user types. It helps users type valid input. If no match shows then they have clue they are not entering an existing value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code (Assuming client name is never empty field and always has name)

```
Private Sub SearchClientRecords_AfterUpdate()
   Dim myclient As String
   If Not IsNull(SearchClientRecords) Then
         myclient = "Select * from [Dashboard] where ([Client Name] = " & Me.SearchClientRecords & ")"
   Else
         myclient = "Select * from [Dashboard] where [Client Name] IS NULL"
   End If
   Me.Dashboard_subform.Form.RecordSource = myclient
   Me.Dashboard_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```